# We calculate moment on this objects (Beam, column, steel profile etc.) How can we calculate the moment and shear force of the object here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, torque

There is a 10N force on the object in the figure. Here I showed the forces on the figure. But how can I calculate the moment and shear force at points in the object or AB Surface? Figure drawing is mine. And it's never a question of homework.
[image]

Comment: Is G an applied load, or what?

Comment: @Bod D 
G weight. I asked the question wrong, I fixed it. How can we find the moment and shear forces at a point or surface inside this object I want?

Comment: @Bob D Ff=Friction force, Fn= Normal force, G=weight

Comment: Is your friction force static or kinetic? I.e., is the object sliding on the surface at constant velocity or is it fixed in position.

Comment: @Bob D Static friction force, no movement here. Bob, I'm a civil engineer, can you help me on whatsapp platform? or here. I do not know the site rules exactly.

Comment: @Bob D 
I think this is a difficult question, nobody can do this question...

Comment: Why are you locating the normal reaction force at the corner of the figure? Shouldn’t it be in line with the COM (G force)? The normal force shouldn’t contribute any moment about the COM. For equilibrium the sum of the moments about any point on the figure should be zero.

Comment: @Bob D 
Normal force is in a position to make the moment zero at all points of the system. Otherwise the system is out of balance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a vector formula, τ = R x F, which lets you calculate the torque produced by a force acting about any chosen point in a static system.  You should find shear defined in any discussion of stress and stain.  A formula relates the force per unit area (carefully defined) with the fractional distortion of the material.

Comment: I guess you did not understand me exactly, for example, the total torque affecting point B is zero. But on B, what is the moment value that forces it to rotate? the subject belongs to Mechanics of Materials.

Comment: You may need to wait for an answer from someone who is familiar with the concept "moment value".